# SSH with Javascript without GUI

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, web, ssh

What I want to make is a Operating System based on Ubuntu which will use the web

I want to make the items clickable. If you click on an app-icon, the application will open. I tried to use WebSockets, but they are'nt that easy to use.

I tried PHP, with exec(), popen(), system() and I tried ssh2 functions. Doesn't work or too slow.

I can't use a GUI like shellinabox, because I only want to connect to localhost and run some commands like 'firefox' or 'sensible-browser' or like 'gedit'. That's why I want help.

I googled the whole day and found nothing. I'm searching for a simple solution. Just a connection and just some commands. No extra GUI, just that simple things!

Thanks,
Amanush.

-------------------------------------------[SECOND QUESTION (EDIT)]------------

I made my own protocol and it's working well!

One last question. My html:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="cloudje:firefox">Open firefox</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c gedit
Name[en_US]=Gedit
Comment[en_US]=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
Name=TunesViewer
Comment=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/tunesview.svg
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/cloudje;
Comment[en_US.utf8]=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
```

Tutorial: http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/

Ok, it's always executing gedit. The reason is the line Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c gedit.

That's cool, but I want to run firefox as well, with 'cloudje:firefox' in the HTML-file. How can I replace -'-c gedit' with '-c firefox', '-c skype' or '-c sensible-browser', automaticly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do...

1. Make a UI for Ubuntu that runs in a browser (like ChromeOS) and launches programs on the local machine?

2. Make a UI that runs programs on a remote machine?

Comment: are working with gnome3 or unity?

Comment: Making a browserbased OS, like JoliOS. You click on an item, it will launch with WebSockets. The point is, I'm not using JoliOS and WebSockets aren't that nice.
It's not important if I am using gnome or unity. I care about making SSH connections with Javascript and running commands on the same computer using a SSH-server. I will use Chromium.

Comment: @all this not a web question. Note that Ubuntu uses javascript for the desktop as well

Comment: This is a web question. Because I am using HTML, CSS, JS and that kind of things ;)

Comment: @Amanush You need to do the second part of my answer. Instead of "gedit" you need an "application handler" to handle the request. So the protocol "cloudje:" points to your ".desktopfile", it will execute the application defined at "Exec". Your need to write a handler application to put in the "Exec" tag to handle the request. You will be able to pass the calling "URL" to the "Exec" application handler so that you can execute the correct application. You can use a bash script, php script (called with the phpd), python, etc... Let me know if this does not make sense i will try to elaborate.

Comment: I wrote a python script, I said. Nevermind, already fixed! Thanks, btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you register a custom protocol handler for your OS on the machine.

ie.: mysweetos://launchapp/chromium

you can find info about this with a quick google of "registering a custom protocol handler linux"

You would have to write some software/script on the linux machine to receive this request and execute the required application.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I want to serve it from an external website, but the idea is great! Maybe is a Chrome addon a good idea?

Comment: If you want to serve it from an external website, the only option is the protocol handler. It is the same way that Steam launches games. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Never thought about Steam. They are almost doing the same thing. Now Googling 'protocol handler'.

Comment: I've got another question, you can all read it below my first one :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.geek.com/news/gtk-html-5-update-puts-desktop-apps-on-the-web-1330027/) looks very similar, and could be a significant part of what you are trying to accomplish. Technical details [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/03/15/gtk-html-backend-update/), looks like it requires GTK3.2+